# Wordpress plugins not working in internet explorer v9 and up

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, internet-explorer, plugins

I have a wordpress site, with a quiet a few plug-ins active. These all function correctly in chrome, safari and firefox although Internet Explorer seems to be a pain.

I once had issues with the same two plug-ins across all browsers, although after nominating the below pages to load without 'AJAX' transitions for pages, it has been working across all browsers except IE.(These plugins claim they are compatible with IE v9 and up)

Two Plugins that are not functioning and there locations:

Modal Popup Box For Visual Composer - http://www.gjwalsh.com.au/who-we-are/ (team members tab)
DP Pro Event Calendar - http://www.gjwalsh.com.au/key-dates/

It makes me wonder if IE is still loading AJAX transitions for pages? How would I force it to not, or is the issue here, a loading order of scripts?

Any help is appreciated, even willing to hire someone if they can solve it! Desperate at this point...

Comment: Hello , which WadaPress plugin u r using Tell name or Give URL

Comment: Plese paste some code u tried,Check for javascript , jQuery console error

Comment: DP Pro Calenda - http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-pro-event-calendar/2485867

Modal Popup Box for Visual Composer - http://codecanyon.net/item/modal-popup-box-for-visual-composer/7155037?WT.ac=portfolio_item&WT.z_author=BrainstormForce

I am yet to try any code, although the theme offers placement of URLs to disable AJAX page transitions.

Also the site loads perfectly through IE v11

Comment: Paid, have already asked for support, but yet to receive a response... Ive also deactivated the theme and a bunch of plug-ins then cleared cache but still not working :(

Comment: How can i use and try it ? :) u say its Paid , so i cant test  . So u wont get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had conflict with another plugin,
Feed Them Social - Version 1.4.7 | By SlickRemix.
Once removed all was working well in IE 9, 10, 11